# use variable name in place of attribute value in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using below piece of terraform code to find the laster version task definition ARN.

```
data "aws_ecs_task_definition" "mongo" {
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.mongo.family
}
```

Now, I want to use a variable like local.task_def_name in place of mongo like this.

task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.${local.task_def_name}.family

The above statement is not working while running the terraform plan command. tried to put in double quotes but didn't work.

Comment: Make sure `locals` is set to the top-level path.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not possible since Terraform does not allow variables in resource names. But if you have multiple resources of the same type, you can try creating them using `for_each`, where a unique name is used as the key. For example:

```js
locals {
  databases = ["admin", "game", "history"]
}

resource "sql_database" "db" {
  for_each = toset(local.databases)
  name = "${each.key}-db"
#...
}
```

In this case, several objects with different indexes will be created in the `sql_database.db` resource. Terraform will allow you to access the fields of a specific object through this index, for example `sql_database.db["admin"].name`. And then you can use such a schema in the `data` object.

```
variable "db_name" {
  default = "admin"
}

data "sql_database" "db" {
  name = sql_database.db[var.db_name].name
}
```